# When making a score for a flappy bird clone, it gives an error when tranforming an int variable to a string one to display it in a text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flappy-bird-clone

I am new to Unity so Im making a flappy bird game to learn the basics. When creating the score, I had to tranform an int variable int oa string variable, but it doesnt work. Here is the code (Written in Visual Studio):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int PlayerScore;
    public Text ScoreText;

    public void addScore()
    {
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore + 1;
        ScoreText = PlayerScore.ToString();
    }

}
```

The ToString method at the end doesnt work. It gives me the following error: You cannot transform type string in UnityEngine.UI.Text. I dont understand it. I dont know a lot of Unity so some help would be apreciated. Thanks!

I was trying to make a flappy bird score. I tryed making a variable with that information (string PlayerScoreText = PlayerScore.ToString();), finding other methods that could help, closing and reopening the game and trying to understand what the error means but I dont know whats wrong

Comment: I don't know Unity3D in details, but it looks to me `Text` is a UI element displaying text data. Therefore, a variable of type `Text` can only hold instances of type `Text`, not instances/values of type `string`. Visit the online Unity3D scripting/API documentation and try finding the respective API documentation for the `Text` type. Read what the purpose of this type is. And further peruse the documentation of the members (methods/properties) of the `Text` type to find which of its methods or properties will allow you assign a string value to a `Text` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you're doing is 90% correct but you are missing your ScoreText is needing the .text after it.

Try:

`ScoreText.text = PlayerScore.ToString();`

The Unity documentation shows it also like this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unity/unity_text_element.htm

Comment: That's odd that Unity uses a lowercase public property names.

Comment: I agree. In fact, when I originally posted my answer I had the property as uppercase and then had to change it.

Comment: haha I did the same when I edited your answer. I thought it was a typo but then I went and checked the docs just to be sure.

Comment: Sneaky unorthodox Unity :)

Answer (score 1):

the fix is easy my friend  `Text ScoreText` refers to the **Text component** but you need to access **the text area** attribute in the Text Component ScoreText so to do so you need to put this code `ScoreText.text = PlayerScore.ToString();`
the part where you where wrong isn't the parsing of the int but tryin to affect a string to a UI component